# Why is my Java programme not calculating the correct answer?

Tags: numbers, calculation

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConvertingLengths {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int meters;
    char response;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many meters?");
    meters = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("To convert it to centimeters, press c, to convert it to millimeters, press m.");
    response = keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);

    if (response == 'c') {
        System.out.println("The answer is " + response * 100 + " centimeters.");;
    }
    if (response == 'm') {
        System.out.println("The answer is " + response * 1000 + " millimeters.");
    }
    keyboard.close();
}
}
```

Here is the problem, when I run the programme, no matter what answer I put for the number of meters, the final conversion to centimeter will always be 9900 and millimeter be 109000.
Here are the pictures.

[centimeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcYnA.png)
[millimeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S0lB.png)

Why is my Java programme not returning the correct numbers?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  FYI, to post code, shift it right 4 spaces in a text editor, copy, and paste.  Best to avoid tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the response variable, which is your 'c' or 'm' character. Use the meters variable instead

```
System.out.println("The answer is " + meters * 100 + " centimeters.");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in what variables you are using.

```
if (response == 'c') {
  System.out.println("The answer is " + response * 100 + " centimeters.");;
}
if (response == 'm') {
  System.out.println("The answer is " + response * 1000 + " millimeters.");
}
```

The math uses the response variable which is not correct.  The first line is c, which will use the ascii code of 99.  That times 100 = 9900.  On the other line, when response = n, that is ascii code of 109.  That gives you 109000.

You want to use meters instead of response.